# Unable to run Flask app using development server

Tags: python, flask

I am unable to run a Flask app in the Flask development server. My project structure is like this:

```
main-repo/
-   app-config/
        app.conf
        app.wsgi
-   src/
    -   app-repo/
            app.py
```

To run the app I export the following environment variables

```
$ export FLASK_APP=/full/path/of/app.py
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ flask run
```

I get the following error though when I point the browser to the test URL `http://localhost:5000/`:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: The file/path provided (app-repo.app)   does not appear to exist. Please verify the path is correct. If app is not on   PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

Comment: I note that Flask appears to be using Python 3, not Python 2.7. How do I make Flask explicitly use Python 2.7?

Comment: Use virtualenv: `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2 venv`

Comment: It does not work - the call to `flask run` is going to Python 3.5 flask.

Answer (score 0):

make a new virtual environment

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

Activate it

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Re-install Flask in virtual environment

```
pip install flask
```

and now run the flask app

```
flask run
```

Comment: I get the same error: `NoAppException: The file/path provided (app-repo.app) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py`. This is even after I add the full path of the app to `sys.path`.